# Shell stops execution of commands after an if;then condition

Tags: linux, bash

Here the snippet of code I am using. As you see shell stops execution and doesn't continue with the elif statement.

```
if [[ $( cat /tmp/findout |wc -l) -ge 1 ]];then
 echo "Found files older than 14 days and deleting them......"
 xargs -d'\n' rm -v </tmp/findout 
elif [[ $(du -sm /var/log |awk '{print $1+0}') -ge $cdu ]];then
 echo "Verifying the /var/log usage......"
 fsusage
```

```
[root@myhost]# sh rvarlog_util.sh
Found files older than 14 days and deleting them......
removed ‘/var/log/messages-20190210’
removed ‘/var/log/pxp-agent.log-20190313.gz’
removed ‘/var/log/pxp-agent.log-20190315.gz’
removed ‘/var/log/cron-20190210’
removed ‘/var/log/pmd.log.6.gz’
removed ‘/var/log/cron-20190303’
removed ‘/var/log/pxp-agent.log-20190309.gz’
[root@myhost]#
```

Comment: Of course not; the `elif` condition is only checked if the preceding condtion in the same `if` statement is false. You probably just want a separate `if` statement instead.

Comment: Yeah, `elif` litterally means "If the preceding condition **IS NOT TRUE** then try this one. In your case, the first condition **IS TRUE**, so the `elif` never gets executed.
Also, aren't you missing an `fi` at the end?

Comment: @chepner,I am a beginner. Let me try what you've suggested

Comment: if [[ $( cat /tmp/findout |wc -l) -ge 1 ]];then
 echo "Found files older than 14 days and deleting them......"
 xargs -d'\n' rm -v </tmp/findout 
fi

if [[ $(du -sm /var/log |awk '{print $1+0}') -ge $cdu ]];then
 echo "Verifying the /var/log usage......"
 fsusage
 echo "If you still find the /var/log used % to be above 75,Please capture the output obtained send it to me"
fi
exit

Comment: I've changed the code as pasted above however right after the execution of line 'xargs -d'\n' rm -v </tmp/findout ' the shell stops execution

Comment: Is the purpose of the `if` to check that the file is non-empty, or do you actually care that it contains a newline?  You should probably just do `if test -s /tmp/findout; then ...` OTOH, using xargs with `-d '\n'` is pretty terrible.  I assume `/tmp/findout` is the output of some `find` invocation; just apply a `-delete` option to that.

Comment: @WilliamPursell , I don't really care. Someone had in fact suggested the xargs method and I found that very light and simple. Is that really the problem that's stopping the command execution?

Comment: @ronythomas, the thing that is stopping the execution has already been pointed out.  Namely, it is that you do not understand the semantics of `elif`.  As an admitted beginner, you should care when you use techniques that could easily lead to data loss.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, I thank you and I did replace the elif with a new if line however the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

By adding a ; at the end of the xargs line as shown below helped me

```
 xargs -I{} sh -c 'rm -v {}' </tmp/findout | tee /tmp/srsvar.log >/dev/null 2>&1 ;
 echo "Deleted file names have been stored in /tmp/srsvar.log"
```